# Stopping a scheduled task with a batch file action doesn't stop the program running in the batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I have several scheduled tasks that each execute a (different) batch file. Each batch file calls into the same program, with with separate command line arguments. If I Stop a task while it's running, the program in the batch file still runs. (The batch file is a one-liner that simply executes the program.)

How can I force the program launched from a batch file to force quit when I Stop the task that calls the batch file?

As a work around, I'm look for the task in the running processes, and kill it by process id. I'd like a cleaner solution that's managed from the Task Scheduler.

Comment: Did you know the name of the process launched by your batch ? or edit your question and post your batch code.

To list all scheduled tasks type this command line `Schtasks /query /fo LIST`

Comment: Also interested in solution. It's properly killing the process on one Windows 10 machine but not killing it on another Windows 10 machine. Incredible

Comment: I never did follow up here. Since our batch files were just since line commands, we just side-stepped the batch file entirely, and had the trigger run the commands directly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to stop a program called from a batch file from the task scheduler.

The task scheduler only knows about the batch file it has launched.  As such, it can only interact with that running process, not any other process that may have spawned from it.

Your best bet would be to forgo the batch files and run the executable directly in the scheduled task.  That way it would know where the EXE was located as a process and be able to stop it.

Comment: OP responded with this resolution in Oct 2020.  See comments above